# Testing $httpBackend on my controller failing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

When mocking $httpBackend, if I respond with an object the expectation fails the test. However if I respond with a string there are no issues.

here is a plnkr I created: http://plnkr.co/iRKOG7

if you change

```
var data = "one"
```

to

```
var data = {key: "one"}
```

the expectation will fail. Any clues why that is so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The httpBackend returns a copy of your object, just like a real server would do, instead of returning a reference to the object. You should thus use

```
expect($scope.data).toEqual(data);
```

The rationale is explained in this angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5265